# Download data from dynamic button with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have some code than download CSV/HTML data from webpages without any problem. The code is something similar to this:

```
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & conexion, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "FunctionRollupMTO"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

The problem is than the webpage (originally in the variable *conexion*) is beeing updated and now the data is different. For downloading the data, there is a button for "Download CSV" but the link for that button is not always the same (the URL is generated every time the user press the button).

There is a way to emulate VBA to press that button? Or maybe a different way of connect to that webpage? I've been trying MSXML2 but sincerely I don't really understand its way of work.

Thanks!

Comment: If the URL page uses an obsolete code that Internet Explorer can deal, use the browser automation with IE. Also Selenium Basic is a good option to 'click' on the button. In this case you have to get both the driver (Chromedriver, Edge, Firefox, etc) and Selenium installed on the machine.

Comment: private or public url?

Comment: @QHarr is a private URL, but I'm already logged in I think. Don't really know.

Comment: @ALeXceL how is the Selenium option works? The link is not valid on Internet Explorer, unforunately...

Comment: Install Selenium Basic 2.0.9.0: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic, then download Chromedriver.exe: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/104.0.5112.79/chromedriver_win32.zip >>> unzip it saving the exe on the same path that Selenium is installed (there will be an old version on that folder). On the Workbook add the reference to Selenium Basic Library. There are good examples here and in www on using  google chrome+chromedriver+selenium. Good luck!